# Reasons for mysql 5.6 MATCH () AGAINST() not to work

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, codeception, match-against

I am trying to use the full text search in mysql. Basically it works. However...

When I run tests using Yii and codeception a few times tests concerning the match against start to fail.

At some point (usually when i restart the development virtual machine (vagrant) but sometimes just after a while) the Query

```
SELECT * FROM activities WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('efter' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

returns no results anymore

Note i say anymore because when i do a mysqldump of the failing database and reload it again the query works and the tests happily succeed.

Does anyone have any pointers to what might be going on here?

Content in the database gets loaded trough fixtures.

Mysql 5.6.21
Yii 1.1.14
Codeception 2.0.10